# I'm seeing a warning that I can't resolve

Tags: reactjs, daterangepicker

[image]

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `object` supplied to `DateRangePicker`, expected an array.

[image]

I'm seeing a warning that I can't resolve.

Answer (score 2):

range picker requires a range of dates with `start` and `end` dates

```
const [date, setDate] = useState([new Date(), new Date() ]);
```